# How to remove zero columns from array

Tags: matlab

I have an array which looks similar to:

```
 0     2     3     4     0     0     7     8     0    10
 0    32    44    47     0     0    37    54     0    36
```

I wish to remove all

```
0
0
```

from this to get:

```
 2     3     4     7     8    10
32    44    47    37    54    36
```

I've tried `x(x == 0) = []`
but I get:

```
x =

 2    32     3    44     4    47     7    37     8    54    10    36
```

How can I remove all zero columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
x(:,all(x==0))=[]
```

Answer (score 3):

You had the right approach with `x(x == 0) = [];`.  By doing this, you would remove the right amount of elements that can still form a 2D matrix and this actually gives you a **vector** of values that are non-zero.  All you have to do is [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html) the matrix back to its original form with 2 rows:

```
x(x == 0) = [];
y = reshape(x, 2, [])

y =

     2     3     4     7     8    10
    32    44    47    37    54    36
```

---

Another way is with [`any`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/any.html):

```
y = x(:,any(x,1));
```

In this case, we look for any columns that are non-zero and use these locations to index into `x` and extract out those corresponding columns.

Result:

```
y =

     2     3     4     7     8    10
    32    44    47    37    54    36
```

---

Another way which is more for academic purposes is to use [`unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html).  Assuming that your matrix has all positive values:

```
[~,~,id] = unique(x.', 'rows');
y = x(:, id ~= 1)

y =

     2     3     4     7     8    10
    32    44    47    37    54    36
```

We transpose `x` so that each column becomes a row, and we look for all unique rows.  The reason why the matrix needs to have all positive values is because the third output of `unique` assigns unique ID to each unique row in sorted order.  Therefore, if we have all positive values, then a row of all zeroes would be assigned an ID of 1.  Using this array, we search for IDs that were not assigned a value of 1, and use those to index into `x` to extract out the necessary columns.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`sum`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html).
Sum over the columns and any column with zeros only will be zeros after the summation as well.

```
sum(x,1)
ans =

    0   34   47   51    0    0   44   62    0   46
```

---

```
x(:,sum(x,1)>0)

ans =

    2    3    4    7    8   10
   32   44   47   37   54   36
```

Answer (score 0):

Also by reshaping `nonzeros(x)` as follows:

```
reshape(nonzeros(x), size(x,1), [])

ans =

     2     3     4     7     8    10
    32    44    47    37    54    36
```